# Mutually congruent solutions to $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0\pmod{p}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can i find the number of mutually congruent soltuions to $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0\pmod{p}$ where p is a prime. I know for  $p=3$, there is 1 solution $(0,0)$, and when $p=5$, there are $9$ solutions but i need a general form .Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Presumably, you mean that $(x,y)$ is mutually congruent if $x \equiv y \pmod p$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distinguish three cases,

1. $p = 2$, then we have the two incongruent solutions $x\equiv y \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$ and $x \equiv y \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$.
2. $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, then there is only the trivial solution $x \equiv y \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$.
3. $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, then for every $x \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, there are exactly two residue classes such that $x^2+y^2\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, namely $y \equiv \pm \xi\cdot x \pmod{p}$, where $\xi$ is the modular square root of $-1$ that is less than $p/2$ (just to fix it uniquely), that gives you $2(p-1)$ pairwise incongruent solutions. Then there is also the trivial solution $x\equiv y \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, so in total you have $2p -1$ pairwise incongruent solutions.